# SwiftUI Picker OnChange not being called when new option is being selected

Tags: swiftui, onchange, picker

SeasonData is an array of objects of type Season

userData holds 2 [INT]
lastUsedSeason -> which reference the last 3array positions of SeasonData that were accessed [3,1,0]

arrayPosition holds [0,1,2].

These are loaded from a file.

The display and selection of this picker works correctly. However I cannot figure out how to get the onChange to fire when changing a selection.

```
    struct UserData: Codable {
      var lastUsedSeason: [Int]
      var arrayPosition: [Int]
    
     mutating func addLastUsedSeason(index: Int) {
        if (lastUsedSeason.count > 3){
          lastUsedSeason.insert(index, at: 0)
          lastUsedSeason.remove(at: 2)
        }
      }
    }

    @main
    struct SandStats_New_App: App {
      @StateObject private var modelData = ModelData()
      
      @State private var showSeason = false
      
      
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
              ContentView(seasonSelected: $showSeason)
                .environmentObject(modelData)
                .frame(minWidth: 700, minHeight: 300, alignment: .topLeading)
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .commands {
              SandStatCommands(addSeasonButton: $showSeason, modelData: modelData)
            }
        }
    }

struct SandStatCommands: Commands {
  var modelData : ModelData
  @Binding var addSeasonButton: Bool
  @State var seasonSelection: Int = 0

  var body: some Commands {
    
      CommandMenu("Season"){
        
        Button("Add Season"){
          addSeasonButton = true
        }
        Picker(selection: $seasonSelection, label: Text("Selected Season")){
          ForEach(modelData.userData.arrayPosition, id:\.self) { index in
            Text(modelData.seasons[modelData.userData.getLastUsedSeason(index1: index)].seasonName()).tag(index)
          }
        }.onChange(of: seasonSelection, perform:  { value in
          print(value)
        })
        
        Button("save Index"){
          saveData(for: modelData.userData, to: "userData")
        }
      }
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `seasonSelection` to work in a `Picker`,  add a `.tag()` to `Text(...)` and make sure it is of the same type as the  `seasonSelection`, for example (assuming `index` is of type Int):

NOTE: this works for macCatalyst, for macOS only, see EDIT.

```
Picker(selection: $seasonSelection, label: Text("Selected Season")){
  ForEach(userData.userData.lastUsedSeason, id:\.self) { index in
    Text(seasonData.seasons[index].seasonName()).tag(index)  // <-- here
  }
}
 .onChange(of: seasonSelection, perform:  { _ in
  seasonData.seasons[0].testPrint()
 })
```

EDIT: sample code that shows how to use `tag` with `seasonSelection` in `.onReceive()` on macOS only, and `.onChange()` for macCatalyst.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@main
struct TestMacApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("demo").frame(width: 480.0, height: 320.0)
        }
        .commands {
            SandStatCommands()
        }
    }
}

struct SandStatCommands: Commands {
    @State var seasons = ["Spring","summer","autumn","winter"]  // array of values
    @State var seasonSelection: Int = 0  // <-- here initial selection
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Season"){
            Button("Add Season"){
                seasons.append(String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(6))) // for demo, add a random name
            }
            Picker(selection: $seasonSelection, label: Text("Selected Season")){
                ForEach(0..<seasons.count, id:\.self) { index in
                    Text(seasons[index]).tag(index)  // <-- here tag
                }
            }
           // .onChange(of: seasonSelection) { value in
           //     print("---> seasonSelection value: \(value)")
           //  }
          .onReceive(Just(seasonSelection)) { value in
             print("---> seasonSelection value: \(value)")
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I updated the code (now reflected in the original post). I included the tag with an index whichI know if correct because I am using it to access information in another array. However when I add the .tag(index) The picker doesn't show the initial selection or show a check when making another selection. Index is of type Int so i'm not sure where the disconnect is happening. Should I not be using the Id:\.self in this case?

Comment: to debug your code you will need to provide more info, specially on  `userData.userData.arrayPosition`. Is this an array of Int?

Comment: Note: you should not have the `@StateObject` in your `SandStatCommands`.
 Pass these in as `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject`.
 Also you use `addSeasonButton` but this is not declared.

Comment: updated my answer with demo code that you can customise for your purpose.

Comment: I have updated the code based on your feedback. The picker is now working properly. However it seams the onChange is still not firing.  I am not seeing anything displayed in the console.  Thank you for your continued feedback.

Comment: The `.onChange(..)` works for me in my tests. Without all the code you use, it is not possible to debug your problem.
My advice is,  you should reconsider your code structure. 
Manipulating index like you do, is not a good way to go. 
Note, in `SandStatCommands` you should have `@ObservedObject var modelData : ModelData`.
If my answer helped you, could you mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your solution makes sense. I do have one final question. I ran your code as is and I do not get the print statement showing up in my console when I select a new season. I am assuming that is where you are seeing it when you run your code, or am i mistaken.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I have been testing my code on MacCatalyst where it all works well.
On MacOS **only** App, I do not see any print either when I use the `.onChange(of: seasonSelection) {...}`.
However, you can use `.onReceive(..)` instead to make it work. I'll updated my answer with this option.
Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For future users long story short:

`onChange` does not gets called when 'seasonSelection' is `Int` and you are trying to set `String` to it.

XCode does not gives any error message/crash to figure out what's wrong.

```
  @State var seasonSelection: String = "default" // keep this 'default' as the value you want to show on opening picker
  //leaving it blank will select 0th index ""
```